# longtable with long equation in acmart latex format

Tags: equations, longtable, acmart

I am finding difficulty in making longtable with long equations in acmart format

```
          \documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}



           \AtBeginDocument{%
            \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
           \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern- 
         0.8em\TeX}}}

      %% Rights management information.  This information is sent to you
       %% when you complete the rights form.  These commands have SAMPLE
          %% values in them; it is your responsibility as an author to 
    replace
    %% the commands and values with those provided to you when you
    %% complete the rights form.
     \setcopyright{acmcopyright}
   \copyrightyear{2018}
         \acmYear{2018}
       \acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}



       %% These commands are for a JOURNAL article.
          \acmJournal{JACM}
         \acmVolume{37}
       \acmNumber{4}
        \acmArticle{111}
      \acmMonth{8}

        %%
          %% Submission ID.
           %% Use this when submitting an article to a sponsored event. 

       %% You'll receive a unique submission ID from the organizers
       %% of the event and this ID should be used as the parameter to this command.
            %%\acmSubmissionID{123-A56-BU3}

         %%
       %% The majority of ACM publications use numbered citations and
     %% references.  The command \citestyle{authoryear} switches to the
      %% "author year" style.
   %%
    %% If you are preparing content for an event
       %% sponsored by ACM SIGGRAPH, you must use the "author year" style of
        %% citations and references.
       %% Uncommenting
    %% the next command will enable that style.
    %%\citestyle{acmauthoryear}

    %%
     %% end of the preamble, start of the body of the document source.
     \begin{document}


             % \lipsum[1-3]         % dummy text
     \begin{table*}[b]
   \caption{Different Types of Activation Functions}
       \label{tab:long}
   \setlist[itemize]{  nosep,           % <-- itemize setup
                leftmargin = *,
                before     = \vspace{-.6\baselineskip},
                after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                }
      \setcellgapes{3pt}
        \makegapedcells   % for additional vertical space around cells' 
   contents
      \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=12mm} % all images will have 
        width of cell's width
     \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
 \footnotesize            % for better fit text into cells
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
                |*{2}{>{\raggedright}p{0.1\linewidth}|}
                      c|
                 *{2}{X|}
                        }
       \hline
      \thead{Activation}  & \thead{Figure}        & \thead{Equation}
            &  \thead{Advantages}    & \thead{Disadvantages}    \\
     \hline
   \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
    & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
       & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included 
       equation
          f{x} = \begin{cases}
    x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
(e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
        & \begin{itemize}
     \item Hard variant of Elish
          \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
    \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
           \end{itemize}
      &  good \\
      \hline
        \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
         & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
     & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included 
    equation
       f{x} = \begin{cases}
    x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
   (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
       & \begin{itemize}
       \item Hard variant of Elish
       \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
        \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
   \end{itemize}
  &  good \\
\hline
        \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
       & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
       & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included 
    equation
    f{x} = \begin{cases}
    x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
(e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
       & \begin{itemize}
        \item Hard variant of Elish
         \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
          \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
        \end{itemize}
         &  good \\
           \hline
        \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
        & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
         & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included equation
       f{x} = \begin{cases}
          x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
        (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
       & \begin{itemize}
      \item Hard variant of Elish
     \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
           \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
           \end{itemize}
          &  good \\
         \hline
     \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
      & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
       & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included 
equation
      f{x} = \begin{cases}
    x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
 (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
     & \begin{itemize}
  \item Hard variant of Elish
      \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
     \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
\end{itemize}
  &  good \\
\hline
\textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
   & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
      & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included 
equation
f{x} = \begin{cases}
    x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
(e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
     & \begin{itemize}
      \item Hard variant of Elish
    \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
  \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
\end{itemize}
  &  good \\
\hline
\textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
       & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
    & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included equation
f{x} = \begin{cases}
    x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
(e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
    & \begin{itemize}
     \item Hard variant of Elish
        \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
           \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
             \end{itemize}
  &  good \\
\hline
\textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
       & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
         & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included 
    equation
f{x} = \begin{cases}
    x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
(e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
     & \begin{itemize}
       \item Hard variant of Elish
        \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
     \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
      \end{itemize}
  &  good \\
   \hline
      \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
      & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
         & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included 
    equation
   f{x} = \begin{cases}
    x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
    (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
            & \begin{itemize}
     \item Hard variant of Elish
      \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
       \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
           \end{itemize}
  &  good \\
            \hline
           \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
            & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
    & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included 
        equation
f{x} = \begin{cases}
    x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
(e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
        & \begin{itemize}
      \item Hard variant of Elish
           \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
          \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
          \end{itemize}
   &  good \\
    \hline
          \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
      & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
           & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included equation
      f{x} = \begin{cases}
             x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
       (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
         & \begin{itemize}
       \item Hard variant of Elish
       \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
        \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
       \end{itemize}
        &  good \\
        \hline


          \end{tabularx}
       \end{table*}
          % manually split table
          \begin{table*}[t]
              \ContinuedFloat
         \caption{Different Types of Activation Functions (cont.)}
             \label{tab:long}
         \setlist[itemize]{  nosep,           % <-- itemize setup
                leftmargin = *,
                before     = \vspace{-.6\baselineskip},
                % after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                }
           \setcellgapes{3pt}
          \makegapedcells   % for additional vertical space around cells' 
           contents
      \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=12mm} % all images will have width 
             of cell's width
         \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
         \footnotesize            % for better fit text into cells
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
                |*{2}{>{\raggedright}p{0.1\linewidth}|}
                      c|
                 *{2}{X|}
                        }
          \hline
      \thead{Activation}  & \thead{Figure}        & \thead{Equation}
            &  \thead{Advantages}    & \thead{Disadvantages}    \\
         \hline
       \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
     & \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
          & \raisebox{-4ex}{ $       % need to be set according to included 
      equation
      f(x) = \begin{cases}
               x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))     &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
      (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2}))) &\text{ if }x< 0
        \end{cases}         $}
       & \begin{itemize}
  \item Hard variant of Elish
    \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
     \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
    \end{itemize}
    &  good \\
   \hline
 \end{tabularx}
  \end{table*}
% \lipsum\lipsum    % dummy text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use v 1.59 (this month) template The “acmart” document class includes the “booktabs” package — https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs — for preparing high-quality tables. Table captions are placed above the table. Because tables cannot be split across pages, the best placement for them is typically the top of the page nearest their initial cite.... The contents of the table itself must go in the tabular environment, ......Again, detailed instructions on tabular material are found in the Latex guide http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/acmart/samples/sample-manuscript.pdf

Comment: (i) in your mwe is many errors. please make sure that text after `%` is no manually break into more line (ii) in preamble are missed packages necessary to work your table (iii) please explain what is your problem. in your MWE is no `longtable`  :-(

Answer (score 2):

to long to put in comment ...

- sorry, i have some issues with installed `acmart` document class. so i can't test it on my computer how it works
- in overleaf i see, that `[acmsmall]{acmart}` generate one column document. however, i'm not sure in this, so please check if my observation is correct.
- in case, that it generate one column document, you can use `longtable`,
- i correct your MWE. it should be as follows:

  ```
  \documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
  \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage[demo,
              export]{adjustbox}
  \usepackage{stfloats}
  \usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
  \setcellgapes{3pt}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \setlist[itemize]{nosep,           % <-- itemize setup
                    leftmargin = *,
                    before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
                    after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                    }

  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \begin{document}
      \lipsum[1]                              % dummy text
  \begin{table*}[b]
  \caption{Different Types of Activation Functions}
     \label{tab:long}
  \makegapedcells                             % for additional vertical space around cells' contents
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=12mm} % all images will have width of cell's width
      \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
      \footnotesize                           % for better fit text into cells
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
                          |*{2}{>{\raggedright}p{0.1\linewidth}|}
                                c|
                           *{2}{X|}
                              }
      \hline
  \thead{Activation}  & \thead{Figure}    & \thead{Equation}
          &  \thead{Advantages}    & \thead{Disadvantages}        \\
      \hline
  \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
      &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
          &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
            f{x} = \begin{cases}
          x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
          (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                   \end{cases}$}
          &   \begin{itemize}
          \item Hard variant of Elish
          \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
          \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
              \end{itemize}
              &  good                                             \\
      \hline
  \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
      &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
          &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
            f{x} = \begin{cases}
          x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
          (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                   \end{cases}$}
          &  good
              &   \begin{itemize}
              \item Hard variant of Elish
              \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
              \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
                  \end{itemize}                   \\
      \hline
  \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
      &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
          &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
            f{x} = \begin{cases}
          x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
          (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                   \end{cases}$}
          &   \begin{itemize}
          \item Hard variant of Elish
          \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
          \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
              \end{itemize}
              &  good                                             \\
      \hline
  \end{tabularx}
      \end{table*}
  % manually split table
      \begin{table*}[t]
                \ContinuedFloat
  \caption{Different Types of Activation Functions (cont.)}
  \makegapedcells                             % for additional vertical space around cells' contents
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=12mm} % all images will have width of cell's width
      \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
      \footnotesize                           % for better fit text into cells
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
                          |*{2}{>{\raggedright}p{0.1\linewidth}|}
                                c|
                           *{2}{X|}
                              }
      \hline
  \thead{Activation}  & \thead{Figure}    & \thead{Equation}
          &  \thead{Advantages}    & \thead{Disadvantages}        \\
      \hline
  \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
      &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
          &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
            f{x} = \begin{cases}
          x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
          (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                   \end{cases}$}
          &   \begin{itemize}
          \item Hard variant of Elish
          \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
          \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
              \end{itemize}
              &  good                                             \\
      \hline
  \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
      &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
          &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
            f{x} = \begin{cases}
          x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
          (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                   \end{cases}$}
          &  good
              &   \begin{itemize}
              \item Hard variant of Elish
              \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
              \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
                  \end{itemize}                   \\
      \hline
  \textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
      &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
          &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
            f{x} = \begin{cases}
          x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
          (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                   \end{cases}$}
          &   \begin{itemize}
          \item Hard variant of Elish
          \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
          \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
              \end{itemize}
              &  good                                             \\
      \hline
  \end{tabularx}
      \end{table*}
  \lipsum\lipsum    % dummy text
  \end{document}
  ```

please, test above MWE in tel us, what is actually your problem. also inform us, if your document have only one column. in this case is possible to use for example `ltablex` which is combination of `longtable` and `tabularx` package.

let me note, that this is your third similar question, which differ only in used `\documentclass`. please, decide which document class you actually will use.

**addendum:**
in case, that you really need long table and that you have *one column* document, than try, if the following gives what you after:

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{makecell,
            ltablex}    % new
\keepXColumns
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}                         % for dummy text
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]                            % dummy text
\begingroup
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,           % <-- itemize setup
                  leftmargin = *,
                  before     = \vspace{-.6\baselineskip},
                  after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }
\makegapedcells                             % for additional vertical space around cells' contents
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=12mm} % all images will have width of cell's width
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \footnotesize                           % for better fit text into cells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
                        |*{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.1\linewidth}|}
                              c|
                         *{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
                            }
\caption{Different Types of Activation Functions}
   \label{tab:long}                                             \\
    \hline
\thead{Activation}  & \thead{Figure}    & \thead{Equation}
        &  \thead{Advantages}    & \thead{Disadvantages}        \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{Different Types of Activation Functions (cont)}        \\
    \hline
\thead{Activation}  & \thead{Figure}    & \thead{Equation}
        &  \thead{Advantages}    & \thead{Disadvantages}        \\
    \hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{continued on the next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
    &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
        &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
          f{x} = \begin{cases}
        x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
        (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                 \end{cases}$}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Hard variant of Elish
        \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
        \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
            \end{itemize}
            &  good                                             \\
    \hline
\textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
    &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
        &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
          f{x} = \begin{cases}
        x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
        (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                 \end{cases}$}
        &  good
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item Hard variant of Elish
            \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
            \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
                \end{itemize}                   \\
    \hline
\textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
    &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
        &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
          f{x} = \begin{cases}
        x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
        (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                 \end{cases}$}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Hard variant of Elish
        \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
        \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
            \end{itemize}
            &  good                                             \\
    \hline
\textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
    &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
        &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
          f{x} = \begin{cases}
        x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
        (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                 \end{cases}$}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Hard variant of Elish
        \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
        \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
            \end{itemize}
            &  good                                             \\
    \hline
\textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
    &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
        &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
          f{x} = \begin{cases}
        x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
        (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                 \end{cases}$}
        &  good
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item Hard variant of Elish
            \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
            \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
                \end{itemize}                   \\
    \hline
\textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
    &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
        &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
          f{x} = \begin{cases}
        x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
        (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                 \end{cases}$}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Hard variant of Elish
        \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
        \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
            \end{itemize}
            &  good                                             \\
    \hline
\textbf{Hard Elish}\cite{elish} 2018
    &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{hardelish.jpg}
        &   \raisebox{-4ex}{$       % need to be set according to included equation
          f{x} = \begin{cases}
        x\max(0,\min(1,(\frac{x+1}{2})))        &\text{ if }x\geqslant 0 \\
        (e^{x}-1)\max(0,\min(1,\frac{x+1}{2}))  &\text{ if }x< 0
                 \end{cases}$}
        &  good
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item Hard variant of Elish
            \item Product of Hard Sigmoid and Elu in negative part
            \item Linear and hard sigmoid in positive part
                \end{itemize}                   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

result should be similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: Sorry sir, I knew that it was my third similar question,actually initially I was asked to make it in IEEE latex format ,now in smart, that's why I am finding difficulty, actually this table formation was very difficult for me, as it contains long equations and its a multipage table, but you helped me a lot continuously,  I think this table should work in my ACM small template....thanks, i will check and tell you

Comment: @DiptiMishra, if you not attent to publish article in some of avm journals,why you not simply use `article`?

Comment: Sir ,i am writing for publishing in acm journal